# Creating radio circular rotating button css and jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I create this script : you can see here [Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/OJodewaF/1/edit)

but my problem is this :
I have 3 section you can see in images

I want pointer stay and point to section that near clicked

for example when mouse clicked on 195 degree so after leave mouse pointer back to right side section or when mouse clicked on 340 degree after leaving the mouse cursur pointer back to left side section and in this script I need just 3 degree 0 , 90 and 180

and other degrees clicked back pointer to near of this degrees

Comment: i cant under stand what is this question problem? can anyone help me?

Comment: the question problem is that there's no problem. Just a question. You should setup a jsBin.com recreating an issue, post the relevant code, than ask for help. You can start by using the one I posted you in my comments.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: i update my question , is this enough?

Comment: Beside you said you created the scrip... :) I cannot see any part of the script that handles "if clicked here -> do this" ... what I mean is that you need some sort of *check* and *response* after a click event. It's terribly easy. My script already gives you the needed degrees, you just need an `if` and tell the script what to do. Also the button design is so unrealistic, the arrow moves but the logo stays in place :)

Comment: I was banning for question asking at last year, i think this question is reason , is good choose to deleting this question?

Comment: No if you ask me :D You should ask on meta.stackoverflow.com. Or at least try to improve your question. Now you hopefully know how to ask questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created something that might help you...
<sub>Just, next time you should provide at least your best try in order to get some answers.</sub>

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/adoxan/4/edit)

```
 <div class="slideButton">
   <div class="slider"></div>
   <div class="pointer"></div>
   <div class="panel"></div>
 </div>
```

```
.slideButton{  
  background-color: hsla(190, 90%, 0%, 1);
  background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/FTt4CCI.png);
  width:101px;
  height:101px;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:56px;
  overflow:hidden;
  cursor:pointer;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.slider{
  position:absolute;
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/tQCNIgo.png);
  width:101px;
  height:101px;
          transition: 0s;
  -webkit-transition: 0s;
}
.pointer{
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/SLzrzp6.png);
  width:101px;
  height:101px;
  position:absolute;
  border-radius:50px;
          transition: 1.2s;
  -webkit-transition: 1.2s;
}
.panel{
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:9px;
  text-align:center;
  width:26px;
  height:26px;
  top:36px;
  left:36px;
  border-radius:30px;
  position:absolute;
  line-height:28px;
  color:#39a;
  background:#444;
  box-shadow:inset 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  border:1px solid #aaa;
            transition: 1.2s;
  -webkit-transition: 1.2s;
}
.slideButton:hover > .panel{
  color:#6ef;  
  transition: 0.2s;
  background:#445;
  box-shadow:inset 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
}
```

```
$('.slideButton').each(function(){

var $el = $(this),
    $sl = $el.find('.slider'),
    $po = $el.find('.pointer'),
    $pa = $el.find('.panel'),
    rad = $el.width()/2 ,
    elP = $el.offset(),
    elPos = { x:elP.left, y:elP.top },
    s = {d:0,p:0},
    s2 = {d:s.d,p:s.p};

function d(e){
    var mPos = {x: e.pageX-elPos.x,y: e.pageY-elPos.y}; 
    var getAtan = Math.atan2(mPos.x-rad, mPos.y-rad);    
    s.d = -getAtan/(Math.PI/180) + 180;
    s.p =  Math.round(s.d*100/360);
    $pa.text(s.p);
}

$el.mousemove(function(e){
  d(e);  
  $el.css({backgroundColor: 'hsla(190, 90%, '+ s.p +'%, 1)'});
  $sl.css({transform:'rotate('+ s.d +'deg)'});
}).click(function(){
  s2 = {d:s.d, p:s.p};
  $po.css({transform:'rotate('+ s.d +'deg)'});
}).mouseleave(function(){
  $el.css({backgroundColor: 'hsla(190, 90%, '+ s2.p +'%, 1)'});
  $sl.css({transition:'0.3s',transform:'rotate('+ s2.d +'deg)'});
  setTimeout(function(){
       $sl.css({transition:'0s'}); 
       $pa.text(s2.p);    
  },210);
});

});
```

Comment: Again, this let us see how helpful people on SO are! +1

Comment: wow you are wonderful

Comment: @Roko thanks for your good answer but Do you know what is my question problem? can you help me for edit my question?

Comment: @MinA I'd like, but you have actually put no effort in asking your question. It's totally unclear what you want and what you tried so far. This is a basic example, but how should the button perform and at which mouse/touch event... you did not explained at all. This is so far what I can help you **http://jsbin.com/IhiJInIT/1/edit** until you edit your question with some code and more information.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan , can you answer this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373764/linkable-javascript-object-and-change-slide