# HTML5 canvas, make image rotate around click to select and drag circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have completed code that has a user click a button (to the right of the canvas), then the image is added to the canvas and is constrained to only move around the circumference of a circle.  In order to move the image the user just needs to click the image and then move the mouse.  To release the image the user simply needs to click where the image goes on the canvas.

Here is a fiddle showing what the current code does. 
http://jsfiddle.net/smacnabb/68awv7sq/9/

**Question:** I am looking to be able to have the images that move around the circumference of the circle rotate while moving around the circumference  of the circle.
This is what I mean:

[image]

Here is a fiddle for the code I added to try and make this happen 
http://jsfiddle.net/smacnabb/68awv7sq/11/

in the handlemousemove method, it calls state.draw() every time the mouse move i'm passing mouseX, mouseY to state.draw.

state.draw() is in addstate method and this was the code I added to make the image rotate

```
var dx = mouseX - centerX;
var dy = mouseY - centerY;
var radianAngle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
context.save();
context.translate(centerX, centerY);
context.rotate(radianAngle);
if (this.dragging) {
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.width + 2, this.height + 2)
}  
context.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y);
context.restore();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: P.S use *radix 10* parameter when using `parseInt` method.

Comment: Hope you'll find some clues exploring this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163948/creating-radio-circular-rotating-button-css-and-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You are close...Take a look at this example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var $canvas = $("#canvas");
var canvasOffset = $canvas.offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;

var radianAngle = 0;
var cx = 225;
var cy = 125;
var radius = 50;

// image loader
var imageURLs = [];
var imagesOK = 0;
var imgs = [];
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/cars.png");
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/plane.png");
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/cars1.png");
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/plane1.png");
loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    imgs.push(img);
    img.onload = function() {
      imagesOK++;
      if (imagesOK >= imageURLs.length) {
        callback();
      }
    };
    img.onerror = function() {
      alert("image load failed");
    }
    img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    img.src = imageURLs[i];
  }
}

var imagesY = 20;
var targets = [];
var selectedTarget = -1;

function start() {
  var n = imgs.length / 2;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var target = imgs[i + n];
    ctx.drawImage(target, 15, imagesY);
    targets.push({
      x: 15,
      y: imagesY,
      width: target.width,
      height: target.height,
      image: imgs[i]
    });
    imagesY += target.height + 10;
  }
}


function handleMouseDown(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  x = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
  y = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
  for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
    var t = targets[i];
    if (x >= t.x && x <= t.x + t.width && y >= t.y && y <= t.y + t.height) {
      selectedTarget = i;
      draw(x, y);
    }
  }
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
  if (selectedTarget < 0) {
    return;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
  mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
  draw(mouseX, mouseY);
}


function draw(mouseX, mouseY) {
  var dx = mouseX - cx;
  var dy = mouseY - cy;
  var radianAngle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
  // Drawing code goes here
  var img = targets[selectedTarget].image;
  ctx.clearRect(100, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // draw the circle
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  // draw the image rotated around the circumference
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(cx, cy);
  ctx.rotate(radianAngle);
  ctx.drawImage(img, radius - img.width / 2, -img.height / 2);
  ctx.restore();
}

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e) {
  handleMouseDown(e);
});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e) {
  handleMouseMove(e);
});
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Select an icon on left by clicking<br>
  Then move mouse to have icon rotate around circle</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
```

Comment: Yea I actually got that from you already lol. You are the biggest help. The code I have is a collection of multiple samples you put together that I pieced together, so you are amazing, anyways I added the line ctx.drawImage(img, radius-img.width/2, -img.height/2) in the past before asking the question and it didn't do anything to help the code.  It didn't make any difference.  You can't see it happening on the fiddle but it is actually rotating, but it's rotating significantly outside of the circle like a much bigger angle.

Comment: I can't get your second fiddle to work--clicking the images does nothing. Anyway, refactor your code to eliminate your points[].  All you need to define any position is an angle relative to centerX,centerY. Then use the code in my example above: (1) start with an image that's vertically aligned at the zero angle (== the 3 o'clock position), (2) translate(centerX,centerY), (3) rotate(state.radianAngle), (4) drawImage(state.image, radius-state.image.width/2.  -state.image.height/2). Good luck with your project!