# Easeljs rotate object using mousemove

Tags: html, canvas, rotation, html5-canvas, easeljs

*I'm working in HTML5 canvas + Easeljs*

I would like to rotate objects in my application using my mouse. Idea is the following: click on an object > circle appears with draggable box > drag this box over the circle makes the object rotate.

It is kinda the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244982/html5-canvas-make-image-rotate-around-click-to-select-and-drag-circle), but I have no clue how to do this in Easeljs.

**To illustrate**
[image: Example]

Now you can rotate objects by clicking the buttons in the top right (L = left, R = right), but I want it to be like here:

[image: Example7]

*Click + drag on white box will make it rotate*

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add listeners to to the stage (or in your case, maybe the playing field Shape) for the `mousedown`, `mousemove`, and `mouseup`. In [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/hb8a7ys8/), I'm just listening to the global `stagemouseup`, `stagemousedown`, and `stagemousemove` events. I don't assign the `stagemousemove` listener until the `stagemousedown` is fired. I then remove it when the `stagemouseup` is fired.

For each `stagemousemove` event, you need to find the angle between your player and the stage mouse position. You can do this will the following formula where `shape` is your player:

```
var angleInRadians = Math.atan2(stage.mouseY - shape.y, stage.mouseX - shape.x);  
var angleInDegrees = angleInRadians * (180 / Math.PI);
```

Then you simply set the `shape.rotation = angleInDegrees`.

[Check out this working example](https://jsfiddle.net/hb8a7ys8/).

Comment: I made a quick edit to this fiddle to make it not reset when you start dragging, so you can continue to rotate it: https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/hb8a7ys8/2/